# Reference Assignment in void method

Tags: java, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference, void

I'm given the following method that is supposed to exchange the first two elements of the array that is passed as an argument to the method:

```
public void exchange(int[] a){
    int c[] = new int[a.length];
    c[0] = a[1];
    c[1] = a[0];
    for(int i = 2; i < a.length; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];
    a = c;
}
```

Why doesn't this method work as intended?

At first I thought i was because c's scope is limited to the method, a reference assignment a = c would not have any effect outside that function, but the method does not work even if I use c as an additional parameter. Can anybody tell me why this method doesn't work, please?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference?rq=1

Comment: You can't change a reference passed by value. All arguments are passed by value in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesnt work because a is just a copied reference to the array, alterations to a, like  a[0] = 1; is reflected in the calling method, because you are changing the target of the reference (i.e the array) not the reference itself.
a = c, does not work because it only changes the local reference to the array not the refernce in the calling method.
See a more in depth explanation here: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

To exchange the first to values simply do:

```
int temp = a[0];
a[0] = a[1];
a[1] = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in java arguments are always `pass-by-value`.

In your example you pass a reference to a object, however this reference is passed by value. In other words, new local variable `a` is created and initialized with the references to your array.

If you want to exchange two values you can do this:

```
public void exchange(int[] a){
    int temp = a[0];
    a[0] = a[1];
    a[1] = temp; 
}
```

But if you do this:

```
public void exchange(int[] a){        
    a = new int[10];    
}
```

then only the local variable `a` references the new array.

Answer (score 2):

This method does not work as intended because this line

```
a = c;
```

changes the value of a reference to `int[]` passed into the `exchange` function without touching the referenced array, because object references are passed by value. If you want to change the content of `a`, switch its elements in place through a temporary variable, or copy `c` into `a` using the [`arrayCopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method or a loop.

Here is a very simple implementation that swaps the two initial elements of your array:

```
public void exchange(int[] a) {
    if (a.length < 2) return;
    int tmp = a[0];
    a[0] = a[1];
    a[1] = tmp;
}
```

Note the check for the minimum length that was missing from your code. It prevents exceptions when an array of zero or one elements is passed to your `exchange` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid having to change the reference by not creating a new array.  This will be simpler and much, much faster.

```
public static void exchange(int[] a) {
    int tmp = a[0];
    a[0] = a[1];
    a[1] = tmp;
}
```

You can't change an argument in a called method in Java, you can only change an object which an argument points to.

Answer (score 2):

You can also return the changed array:

```
public int[] exchange(int[] a){
    int c[] = new int[a.length];
    c[0] = a[1];
    c[1] = a[0];
    for(int i = 2; i < a.length; i++)
        c[i] = a[i];
    return c;
}
```

And use this method in this way:

```
a = exchange(a);
```